Android studio gradle issue for running project
Recently facing the gradle issue. how to fix this one
Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getVariantConfiguration()Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/core/GradleVariantConfiguration;'
com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getVariantConfiguration()Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/core/GradleVariantConfiguration;

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.



Need to run in
Android androdi studio 4.1.3 and gradle 6.5 gradle plugin version 4.1.3

Hard to pin-point at exact issue, without loooking at whole stack-trace. Looks like a network issue, are you sure, you are connect to a network? your AS is not set in offline mode.
Can you share a scan link, if it's not private or corp repo, by running
./gradlew assembleDebug --scan

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi., I have resolved the issue based on the jitpack implementation (https://jitpack.io/#SiimKinks/sqlitemagic/0.23.0), but the compiler is not working. Downloading from maven central am facing this issue.                                                Could not find com.siimkinks.sqlitemagic:sqlitemagic-compiler:0.25.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/siimkinks/sqlitemagic/sqlitemagic-compiler/0.25.1/sqlitemagic-compiler-0.25.1.pom
